Deploying Azure Cloud service (extended support) using AzureResourceGroupDeployment overrideParameters gives JSON error
So Here is the scenario:
I have created a Cloud Service(Extended Support) project. As a Devops engineer I need to create a pipeline in Azure Devops to push package to the azure.
I have followed Publish Cloud Services official guideline to publish cloud service.
So for the task ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope I am using override parameters as follows:
-servicename worker -packageSasUri https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mypackage/202405181456/service.cspkg?<sas-token> -configurationSasUri https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mypackage/202405181456/ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg?<sas-token> -location 'Australia Southeast' -certificateName AccelerusLightWorker -keyVaultName worker-vault -keyVaultResourceGroup rg-worker

YAML file only ARM template deployment:
steps:
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  displayName: 'ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope'
  inputs:
    azureResourceManagerConnection: netsynergy
    subscriptionId: 'id'
    resourceGroupName: 'rg-worker'
    location: 'location'
    csmFile: 'build/bicep/worker.bicep'
    overrideParameters: <above mentioned>

I am using Bicep Template:
param location string
param servicename string

@secure()
param packageSasUri string
@secure()
param configurationSasUri string

param keyVaultName string
param certificateName string
param keyVaultResourceGroup string

# there are other resources as well
resource cloudService 'Microsoft.Compute/cloudServices@2020-10-01-preview' = {
   name:  '${servicename}-worker-${suffix}'
   location: location
   tags: {
       DeployFromVisualStudio: 'true'
    }
    properties: {
      osProfile: <secret>
      packageUrl: packageSasUri
      configurationUrl: configurationSasUri
      upgradeMode: 'Auto'
    }
}

So While running pipeline I am getting following error:

There was an error while overriding '' parameter because of 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')', make sure it follows JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)
Starting template validation.
(node:6460) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
Deployment name is accelerus-20240519-032042-6d1e
(Use node --trace-deprecation ... to show where the warning was created)
There were errors in your deployment. Error code: InvalidDeploymentParameterKey.


Hi @Sundar Singh, what's the latest state of the issue after trying with -location australiasoutheast?

Yes it was issue with the location, thanks. Appreciate that.

Hi @Sundar Singh, thanks for your confirmation. It's great to know the issue was resolved. To help others who have the similar issue, I have updated the solution in my answer below.

According to the error message, there seems to be some issues with the parameters in your Bicep template. To confirm it, try to use Azure CLI to deploy your template on your local machine. See How to use Azure Resource Manager (ARM) deployment templates with Azure CLI for the details.
az deployment group create --name ExampleDeployment --resource-group ExampleGroup --template-file <path-to-template> --parameters storageAccountType=Standard_GRS

If there is the same error, check your template.

Ensure that all parameters are correctly defined in your Bicep file. The error message suggests that there’s an issue with one of the parameters being undefined.
Check if you’re using a parameter that hasn’t been defined in your Bicep file.


Update
Solution: Override location using -location australiasoutheast.

Yes I have tried deploying using deployment both from cli and portal, and it is working. The issue is something with the  overrideParameters.

As a workaround, use AzureCLI@2 task in your pipeline to deploy your Azure Cloud service. I don't have your complete template and will test further on my side to see if I can reproduce the error.

I can't reproduce the error using the template shared by you. In your overrideParameters, you are overriding location via -location 'Australia Southeast', which is invalid. Try with -location australiasoutheast. Testing with overrideParameters: '-servicename zycloudservice -packageSasUri $(packagesasurl) -configurationSasUri $(configurationSasUrl) -location eastasia', it works fine.

I am not sure whether you have shared the complete overrideParameters. The pipeline can't pass validation and run if you use -location 'Australia Southeast'. You will see Encountered error(s) while parsing pipeline YAML when you click Run.
